# Changed OSX 10.13.6 username. Can no longer sudo

Tags: macos

User accounts -> change username. I didn't change the home folder, Just display name + user name.
But, that didn't work? I see my old name "quantum" in the login
I don't see my new username

I'm unable to sudo. "quantum is not part of the sudoers, this incident will be reported"

I'm pissed at the UX here. A few clicks and I no longer have sudo access.

I can't use the new username when logging in. Is my installation completely broken?

`dscl . list /Users`

```
_xcsbuildagent
_xcscredserver
_xserverdocs
daemon
nobody
quantum
root
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixable. If you already have another admin account on the computer, log into that other account and grant admin privs to your recently-renamed account.

If you don't already have another admin account, you can create one by booting into Single User Mode by holding Cmd-S at boot, then following the on-screen instructions to remount the root volume read/write, then do `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`, then `reboot`. This will trigger the first-boot setup assistant to run again, and you can use it to create a new local admin account. Then after using that new account to fix your old account (by re-checking the "Allow user to administer this computer" checkbox for the old account), you could then log back into your old account and delete the new admin account.

I personally wouldn't trust most software to be designed to handle changing the user's "short name" very well, especially when the new short name does not match the user's home directory name. I can just imagine a lot of software engineers never thinking about the fact that these kinds of changes could happen, and thus not writing the code in a way that can handle this kind of change.

Comment: Hi, does doing the Apple Setup erase my old home directory?

Comment: @foo No, it shouldn't touch existing user accounts or home directories, but just to be sure, use a new name for the new account (don't use either of the names you've used for the old account).